# Issuing NVMe Read command via DeviceIoControl

Tags: c, windows, system

I'm trying to read 1 block of data from my NVMe SSD.  I'm setting up the NVMeCmd as followings:

```
NVMeCmd[0] = 2;  //OPC = 2 for I/O Read
NVMeCmd[1] = 1;  //NSID = 1
NVMeCmd[6] = &pMyBuffer[0];  //Set PRP1 to address of buffer
NVMeCmd[10] = 0;  //Start LBA = 0
NVMeCmd[12] = 0;  //1-block read (it is 0-based counting)
```

I also set the QueueID = 1 in the NVME_PASS_THROUGH_IOCTL structure (I have verified I have 11 I/O Submission queues and 1 I/O completion queue.

BUT everytime I issue this command to DeviceIoControl, ::GetLastError() returns 0x45D (i.e. "The request could not be perfrom due to a device I/O error).

Thanxs for any help!

Comment: DeviceIoControl with which code? Do you use  IOCTL_STORAGE_PROTOCOL_COMMAND or any proprietary NVMe driver? Have you seen the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt718131(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: The call is Status = DeviceIoControl(fileHandle,IOCTL_SCSI_MINIPORT,pInOutBuffer,InputBufLen,pInOutBuffer,InputBufLen,&Count,NULL);  pInOutBuffer is a pointer to NVME_PASS_THROUGH_IOCTL.

Comment: Sorry for the post above - I can't seem to get it to format properly (and everytime I hit the 'return key' to skip a line the site posts what I have typed so far - argg..............

Comment: [As documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560512(v=vs.85).aspx), the parameter of IOCTL_SCSI_MINIPORT is a  SRB_IO_CONTROL structure. That does not have NVMeCmd member.